# Apache 2.4 LDAP "password mismatch" but password is correct

Tags: debian, apache-2.4, openldap

I run apache2.4 on debian and LDAP-Auth tells me "password mismatch" but I am very sure I use correct passwords (tested multiple users).

I also asked chat-gpt and it told me maybe my password get hashed differently on server/client but I don't know how to check that.

this is part of my /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

```
<Directory /var/www/html/ldaptest/>
    AllowOverride All
    SSLRequireSSL
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Restricted Area"
    AuthBasicAuthoritative Off
    AuthBasicProvider ldap
    AuthLDAPURL "ldaps://my-domain.de:10636/dc=my-domain,dc=de?uid?sub?(objectClass=*)"
    AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=binduser,DC=my-domain,DC=de"
    AuthLDAPBindPassword "somepass"
    Require valid-user

</Directory>
```

Do you have any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: Are you authenticating against an MS AD DC? Does the bind user contains whitespaces or special characters?

Comment: no, it is no MS AD, it is slapd on debian. the bind user has a "-" in its name. But a simple ldapsearch from my webserver does work, i can look up any user with that. I think the problem is somewhere with my apache config.

Answer (score 0):

The wrong part is here:

```
AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=binduser,DC=my-domain,DC=de"
```

In my case it must be "cn=binduser,dc=ldap-users,dc=my-domain,dc=de"

Brief: Double check structure.